# Question about $C^2$ topology?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry

In Audin's book Morse theory and Floer homology, they claim that

> Proposition 6.1.6. Let $W$ be a compact symplectic manifold and let
> $H : W → \mathbb{R}$ be a function. If $H$ is sufficiently small in the $C^2$ sense, then
> the only solutions of period $1$ of the Hamiltonian system associated with $H$
> are the constant solutions.

I do not know what is sufficiently small in the $C^2$ sense.

Comment: The $C^2$ norm is given by the max of the sup norm of the function, its first derivatives, and second derivatives (in reasonable charts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $\varepsilon  > 0$, $h$ is called
a $C^2$-approximation of $f$ in $n$-dim compact space $U$ if the following three inequalities
hold for all $p \in U$:

$$
|f(p)-h(p)|<\varepsilon,
\qquad|\partial_if(p)-\partial_ih(p)|<\varepsilon ,
\qquad|\partial^2_{ij}f(p)-\partial^2_{ij}h(p)|<\varepsilon,
 $$
for $i,j=1,\dots n.$

Comment: But, what if $f$ and $h$ are on a manifold? In this case, for all compact set in any chart we do the same thing?